# if (isset($_post['submit'])) is not working

Tags: php, forms, post

I'm learning PHP. A beginner. The code from the tutorial I follow is below.

```
    <?php
        if (isset($_POST['submit']) && (!empty($_POST['submit']))) {
            $from = 'Alexey Pazukhin (alexey.pazukhin@mail.ru)';
            $subject = $_POST['subject'];
            $text = $_POST['elvismail'];
            $output_form = FALSE;
              if (empty($subject) && empty($text)){
                echo 'Subject and text fields are empty. <br/>';
                $output_form = TRUE;
              }
              if (empty($subject) && (!empty($text))) {
                echo 'Subject field is empty. <br/>';
                $output_form = TRUE;
              }
              if ((!empty($subject)) && empty($text)) {
                echo 'Text field is empty. <br/>';
                $output_form = true;
              }
              if((!empty($subject)) && (!empty($text))){

                 $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'elvis_store') 
        or die ('Connection failed. MySQL');
                 $query = "SELECT * FROM email_list";
                 $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) 
        or die('DB query error');
                 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                 $first_name = $row['first_name']; 
                 $last_name = $row['last_name'];
                 $msg = "Dear $first_name $last_name, \n $text";
                 $to = $row['email'];
                 mail($to, $subject, $msg, 'From:' . $from);
                 echo 'Message sent:' . $to . '<br/>';
                 }
               mysqli_close($dbc);
              }
          }
        else {
          $output_form = TRUE;
        }

        if ($output_form) {
        ?>
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
        <label for="subject">Subject of email:</label><br />
        <input id="subject" name="subject" type="text" value="<?php echo $subject; ?>" size="30" /><br />
        <label for="elvismail">Body of email:</label><br />
        <textarea id="elvismail" name="elvismail" rows="8" cols="40"><?php echo $text; ?></textarea><br />
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
<?php
}
?>
```

The problem is that code doesn't send any mails after clicking Submit button (either I fill the fields or don't) and returns an empty (new) form in browser (Chrome).

Comment: your button name is `Submit` and on your php code u are checking `submit` not `Submit`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace

```
 <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
```

with

```
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
```

Comment: well i don't think its case sensitive

Comment: @Jigar7521 It *is* case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

you can only check - if(isset($_POST['Submit'])). You dont want to check for !empty.

In your input tag you have given name attribute as name="Submit".

so, use $_POST['Submit']

instead of $_POST['submit']

Because post variables are CASE SENSITIVE.

Answer (score 0):

I'd change `if (isset($_POST['Submit'))` to `if (isset($_POST['sendIt'))`

and then i'd change `<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />`

to:

`<input type="submit" name="sendIt" value="Submit" />`

This way your form has it's own unique send value rather than the bog standard `submit` which could lead to future issues if and when you decide to add anymore forms into the website.